# OpenCV Linker Error

Tags: ios, opencv, linker, linker-errors, video-capture

I've done a lot of searching around so far on this problem, but no proposed solution has worked for me. When running my program, I need to be able to load in a video file to an opencv VideoCapture object so that I can then display it frame by frame. The line

```
vidCap = cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(FILENAME);
```

causes 4 linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(cv::String const&)", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  "cv::String::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::String::~String() in ViewController.o
  "cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      cv::String::String(char const*) in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and nothing has worked for me so far to fix this. When I change the C++ compiler from libc++ to libstdc++ then I get a "lexical or preprocessor issue: 'cstdint' file not found"

Can anyone offer me assistance on this?

Edit:

```
Ld /Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenTracker-frcayvqpvtapigflaqrveexxtkud/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChickenTracker.app/ChickenTracker normal i386
    cd /Users/max/Documents/ChickenTracker
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenTracker-frcayvqpvtapigflaqrveexxtkud/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/max/Documents/ChickenTracker -L/Users/max/Downloads/ios/build/iPhoneSimulator-x86_64/modules/highgui/UninstalledProducts -L/Users/max/Documents/opencv-2.4.7/build/lib -F/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenTracker-frcayvqpvtapigflaqrveexxtkud/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/max/Downloads/ios -F/Users/max/Documents/ChickenTracker -filelist /Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenTracker-frcayvqpvtapigflaqrveexxtkud/Build/Intermediates/ChickenTracker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChickenTracker.build/Objects-normal/i386/ChickenTracker.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -lc++ -framework opencv2 -framework Accelerate -framework CoreImage -framework QuartzCore -framework AssetsLibrary -framework ImageIO -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenTracker-frcayvqpvtapigflaqrveexxtkud/Build/Intermediates/ChickenTracker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChickenTracker.build/Objects-normal/i386/ChickenTracker_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenTracker-frcayvqpvtapigflaqrveexxtkud/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChickenTracker.app/ChickenTracker
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant make/compiler/linker command line(s).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: What build environment/IDE/whatever are you using ? In order to debug this you would ned to be able to see what commands are being passed to the compiler/linker. If you're using a makefile then these should be right in front of you in the terminal window. If you're using and IDE (Xcode, MSVC, Eclipse, etc) then you may have to dig a little.

Comment: Ah right, sorry. Yes, I'm just attempting to compile it straight from Xcode.

Comment: OK, well all the commands are in the Build Results window in that case. I expect you've just forgotten to add the relevant libraries but the build transcript will shed light on this.

Comment: I've added in the build transcript, does this help? I've double checked my libraries, but you might see something I'm missing.

Comment: I have the same issue. How do you solve the problem?